# Creating list of lists in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I am attempting to create a list lists in a for loop from 2 dataframes df3 and df4

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=list('EF'))

l=[]
for i in range(len(df3)-2):
    s=df3[i:i+2].values.tolist()
    s.append(df4.iloc[i+2,1]) #this is what one element looks like and works
    l.append(s)
```

The output I'm getting is

```
[[[[[[[[[''],
    [[[-1.6901730393462748,
       0.9398299757220133,
       0.5402878560205543,
       -0.2355701586445652],
      …..  2.300820924304919]]
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
[[[[-1.6901730393462748,
       0.9398299757220133,
       0.5402878560205543,
       -0.2355701586445652],
      [1.789968968313937,
       0.3792557248306339,
       0.5701432920348918,
       1.3781227005819763]],
     1.087047297584572]],
   [[[1.789968968313937,
      0.3792557248306339,
      0.5701432920348918,
      1.3781227005819763], 
and so on.]]]]
```

I haven't found a thread that is applicable, if there is one, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only fixing your code here, you have lot of problems in your code , for example , for loop should with `range` not `int` , and `ix` will no longer work I am using `iloc` replace it and `list` should using `append`

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(df3)-2):
    s=df3[i:i+2].values.tolist()
    s.append(df4.iloc[i+2,1]) #this is what one element looks like and works
    l.append(s) # this is intended to create a list of all the elements
```

Comment: Yeah cheers, I had defined the range elsewhere but it didn't make it into the original post.